# QPluginLoader with PyQt modules as plugins: possible?

Tags: c++, python, qt, plugins, pyqt

I have a C++ application that loads externals plugins thanks to `QPluginloader`.
`QPluginLoader` provides access to a Qt plugin. A Qt plugin is stored in a shared library (a DLL).

The plugins have to inherit from a pure virtual class ( and `Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE` ) and `QObject`.

I would like to create plugins by using python and `PyQt`.
Is this possible without too much work?
For instance if I have to convert the modules to C++ with `boost::python`, this could be nonsense, as `PyQt` is already a conversion from C++ to Python...

Thanks!

Edit:
I have looked into the doc of pyqt regarding plugins:
http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/pyqt4ref.html#writing-qt-designer-plugins

`PyQT` has a specific class `QPyDesignerCustomWidgetPlugin` for qt designer plugins.
But this class is in the `QtDesigner.pyd` module, so I can not see the code in order to replicate the same architecture.

Edit2:
http://www.boddie.org.uk/david/Projects/Python/Qt/
File pyqt4-embedded-examples-2008-02-13.tar.gz
Contains code sample to integrate PyQt Widget in C++. But you don't use QPluginLoader and have to integrate the python interpretor headers in your C++ main code.

Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Well, I don't think it's possible without too much work. If you write a module in PyQt, chances are that you would have to add the entire Python interpreter to your executable in order to be able to interpret those modules. Even if you translate those modules into C++, the translated functions will have to call the Python API at some point, thus introducing a dependency on Python itself.

Comment: Indeed, I have seen pythonplugin.dll PyQt4\plugins\designer means there is a way to integrate python code as a designer plugin. But I don't know. Thanks

Comment: `pythonplugin.dll` is part of PyQt4, not Qt4. Indeed, it allows you to use Python-based plugins in Qt Designer, but it also calls back to Python in order to interpret those modules. If you load `pythonplugin.dll` into Dependency Walker (see http://www.dependencywalker.com/), you will see that it depends on Python.